# Why in phpmyadmin php file gets downloaded after some time?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am altering a table field. This table has about 30 columns and has 12 million data. So its taking time to execute. After a few minutes of starting, its offering me to download a php file. How can I solve this problem? Please anybody share me your experience.

Comment: did you try re installing phpmyadmin ?? i read about it somewhere will try to get the link to share with you.

Comment: I think this is some kind of time out. I have increased the max_execution_time in php.ini file

Comment: are you not using LIMIT ?

Comment: I am changing the type and default value of a field

Comment: If urgently required use mysql console.